# Gitlab CI: api trigger with axios call not working when using variables

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-api

Without the variables the server call works and gitlab is starting the pipeline.

But when I add variables to that call, it errors: "variables needs to be a map of key-valued strings".

This is my code:

```
    axios
      .post(`https://gitlab.myurl.com/api/v4/projects/${projectId}/trigger/pipeline`, {
        ref: branch,
        token: token,
        variables: { STAGING_AREA: 'testing1', NOTIFY_STATUS: true, SLACK_USER_ID: 'xxxxx' }
      })
      .then(res => {
        console.log('pipeline started:', res.data.web_url);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('errorMessage', error);
      });
```

What is the correct syntax for passing variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was doing one thing wrong.

```
NOTIFY_STATUS: true
```

It seems that *true* can only be passed as a string:

```
NOTIFY_STATUS: 'true'
```

After this edit my code worked just fine.

Comment: very helpful, thank you. Same goes for a timestamp, needs to be converted to string first.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/#making-use-of-trigger-variables), variable parameter should be in the form of `variables[key]=value`.

And the request is a multipart request so you need to use `FormData`.
Try running this code.

```
const pipelineTriggerBody = new FormData();
pipelineTriggerBody.append('ref', 'master'); // branch name
pipelineTriggerBody.append('token', 'CI_TOKEN');
pipelineTriggerBody.append('variables[STAGING_AREA]', 'testing1');
pipelineTriggerBody.append('variables[NOTIFY_STATUS]', true);
pipelineTriggerBody.append('variables[SLACK_USER_ID]', 'xxxxx');

axios
  .post(
    `https://gitlab.myurl.com/api/v4/projects/${projectId}/trigger/pipeline`,
    pipelineTriggerBody
  )
  .then(res => {
    console.log('pipeline started:', res.data.web_url);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('errorMessage', error);
  });
```